# Mail merge for non-techie in Adobe X

Tags: excel, pdf, mailmerge

I need to do a mail merge. Our form is in PDF format. I have my data in an Excel file. Is there an easy way to mail merge?

IF not I have to convert back to Word and do it in there.

I do not program or know how to run scripts etc. so sending me code wont help.

Thanks

Liz

Comment: Hi Elizabeth, this isn't the right forum for your question but we can still help.  First, what did you find when you googled your question? I searched just now for 'mail merge with pdf' and I'm finding a bunch of 3rd party tools that claim to do just that. Do those work for you?

Comment: THank you for letting me know. But I just went ahead and did it using Word. Wanst worth all the effort to do in Adobe for me.

Comment: Good to hear.  I think you chose the right path.

Answer (score 0):

In my company we use regularly [PDF Mail Merger](https://pdfmailmerger.com) for all types of PDF forms that we have to send in bulk. We find it very easy to use.

### Usage:

You will be guided through 4 steps:

1. Upload PDF file
2. Upload Excel file
3. In the Editor you can drag'n'drop placeholders onto the PDF
4. Click to start the PDF generation

### Advantages:

- Works with any kind of PDF file (doesn't require fillable form fields)
- Many spreadsheet formats supported (Microsoft Excel, Open Office Spreadsheet, CSV, TXT etc.)
- New PDF Form templates are set up very quickly
- PDF Form templates can be reused with one click
- No programming knowledge is required

### Disadvantages:

- The free plan only covers the generation of 100 documents

### Screenshots:

[Home Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWDJn.png)

[Upload PDF File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOyHs.png)

[Editor for drag'n'drop placeholders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dErus.png)

[Note: I posted the same answer for a similar question]